# Scala Reflection : Given a getter Symbol, what is the easiest way to find the corresponding setter Symbol?

Tags: scala, reflection, deep-copy

Short version:
Given a getter Symbol I would like to find the corresponding setter Symbol.

Long version:

Below is a little utility class for Scala Reflection.

I plan to use this class to deep copy Hibernate Entities (subclasses of the abstract class `UUIDEntity`).

I divide the deep copy into two parts, 1) value copy each object in the object graph 2) connect the isolated copies to form a cloned object graph. This question only deals with the first part.

Let `root` be an Entity.

First, I want to create a value copy of `root`, let's call this `copy`. Value copy means that I only fill up the value fields in the copy (see definition of value fields below).

This should happen in the `getValueCopy` method.

There is val `copy` but its fields are still empty after creating it with `val copy= constructorMirror.apply()`

So I need to copy the fields from `root` into `copy`. For this I need to get the setters and getters of the fields (more precisely, value fields which are fields that refer to value classes like Int, String, Long etc.).

So far I managed to find the getters for value fields (`valueGetters`), however, my problem is that I want to find the corresponding setters. But I don't really know what is the best way to pair up the setters with the getters?

Is using the method names the only way to go? That is what I would naively do but my feeling tells me that there must be a better way.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks for reading.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import java.util
import model.UUIDEntity
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable


case class ReflectionOfEntity(root:AnyRef) {
 // require(root.isInstanceOf[UUIDEntity[_]])  
  val rtmMirror                   =runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror : InstanceMirror =rtmMirror.reflect(root)
  val classSymbol    : ClassSymbol    =rtmMirror.reflect(root).symbol
  val classMirror    : ClassMirror    =rtmMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)

  val theType        : Type           =rtmMirror.reflect(root).symbol.toType


  val methods        : Iterable[MethodSymbol]=
    theType.declarations.filter(_.isMethod).map(_.asMethod)

  val constructorSymbol:MethodSymbol=methods.filter{m=>m.isConstructor && m.paramss.flatten.
    isEmpty}.headOption.
    getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("no parameterless constructor in root!") )

  val constructorMirror: MethodMirror = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol)


  val valueGetters:Iterable[Symbol]=theType.members.filter{
    case ms:MethodSymbol=>ms.isGetter && isValueType(ms.returnType)
    case _ => false
  }

  def isValueType(tpe:Type)=
    List(typeOf[String],typeOf[AnyVal],typeOf[java.lang.Long]).exists{tpe <:< _}

  def getValueCopy= {
    val copy= constructorMirror.apply()
    val copyR=ReflectionOfEntity(copy)
    //valueGetters.foreach()
    copy
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MethodSymbol` exposes `isCaseAccessor`, `isGetter`, `isSetter`, `accessed` for the field and `setter` for the setter.

I could use the practice if code is needed, but probably not.

Am I looking at different ScalaDoc than you?  Sometimes it's hard to know where to look.

Edit: actually it's on `TermSymbolApi`.

Update:

```
scala> class C(var i: Int, var s: String)
defined class C

scala> typeOf[C].declarations.filter(s => s.isMethod && s.asMethod.isGetter && s.asMethod.setter != NoSymbol)
res10: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(method i, method s)

scala> .map { s => val m = s.asMethod ; (m, m.setter) }
res11: Iterable[(reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol, reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol)] = List((method i,method i_=), (method s,method s_=))
```

Comment: Yes, I understand how to get getters or setters but the problem is finding the getter-setter **pairs**. In other words for every getter I would like to know its corresponding setter.

Comment: From the getter, accessed.setter is the setter, right?  I only looked at the doc and didn't refresh my memory with my fingers.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out, reading the ScalaDoc I would have not figured this out on my own.

Comment: ScalaDoc says for accessor: Backing field for an accessor method, NoSymbol for all other term symbols. Now, what is a backing field? Is the field which is being accessed?

Comment: Updated, just get setter from getter. But yes, accessed is that field (in java terms).

Comment: And add `s.asMethod.setter != NoSymbol` to the filter to ensure there is a setter.